# Case in select after sum?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum, case, between

I'm trying to assign a different column to a sum depending on the dates. 
Here's what I have:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) CASE WHEN date BETWEEN '1/1/13' AND '1/1/14' THEN Last_yr_tot 
        WHEN date BETWEEN '1/1/14' AND 'now' THEN YTD
```

My entire query.

```
select  fd.location_cd
    ,round(sum(case when fd.fs_dt between '1/1/13' and '12/31/13' then amount else 0 end)::numeric, 0) as Last_yr
    ,round(sum(case when fd.fs_dt between '1/1/14' and current_date then amount else 0 end)::numeric, 0) as YTD
    ,round(sum(case when date_part('month', fd.fs_dt) = 1 then amount end)::numeric, 0) January_data
    ,round(sum(case when date_part('month', fd.fs_dt) = 2 then amount end)::numeric, 0) February_data
    ,round(sum(case when date_part('month', fd.fs_dt) = 3 then amount end)::numeric, 0) March_data
    ,round(sum(case when date_part('month', fd.fs_dt) = 4 then amount end)::numeric, 0) April_data
    ,round(sum(case when date_part('month', fd.fs_dt) = 5 then amount end)::numeric, 0) May_data
    ,round(sum(case when date_part('month', fd.fs_dt) = 6 then amount end)::numeric, 0) June_data
    ,round(sum(case when date_part('month', fd.fs_dt) = 7 then amount end)::numeric, 0) July_data
    ,round(sum(case when date_part('month', fd.fs_dt) = 8 then amount end)::numeric, 0) August_data
    ,round(sum(case when date_part('month', fd.fs_dt) = 9 then amount end)::numeric, 0) September_data
    ,round(sum(case when date_part('month', fd.fs_dt) = 10 then amount end)::numeric, 0) October_data
    ,round(sum(case when date_part('month', fd.fs_dt) = 11 then amount end)::numeric, 0) November_data
    ,round(sum(case when date_part('month', fd.fs_dt) = 12 then amount end)::numeric, 0) December_data

from financial_acct fa
    join financial_data fd
    on fd.acct_no = fa.acct_no

inner join (select sum(fd.amount)
    from financial_data fd
    where fd.fs_dt between '1/1/13' and '1/1/14'
    ) Last_yr
    on fa.acct_no = fd.acct_no

where fa.acct_no = '799-' and fd.fs_dt between '1/1/14' and 'now' 
group by fd.location_cd
    ,fd.fs_dt
order by fd.location_cd
```

It was requested that I put my entire query into the post. I will comply, but it needs more details. acct_no is account number. fs_dt is the date. location_cd is where the code is going.

Comment: Let me know if I answered your question.  I'm happy to clarify anything that might be missing or mistaken.  As it looks like you're a fairly new user, I'll also add a Welcome! :) Be sure to mark answers (checkmark below the votes) and upvote when someone has posted something that is useful.

Comment: "Assign a column" .. Can you please try to make your case clear?

Comment: @paqogomez when I enter those two into there, it gets the same results for both of them, do you know why this is?

Comment: Enter which two into where? Did you check out [my fiddle?](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9490a/5)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I'm trying to make YTD a column and Last_yr_tot a column.

Comment: @user3613495, if you mean that you entered the date column name and table name into my query and got the same result in each column, i could only suggest that the values are equal.  What value are you expecting?

Comment: It is supposed to be a net income for a company. Last_yr is Last year's total income. YTD is this year to date.

Comment: @paqogomez I see what the problem is. In my where clause, there is a condition set where it is between 1/1/14 and now. I have some other columns separated by month that come up from the beginning of time if I get rid of that. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: The case statements act like a where clause in this case, so you'd want to remove any restrictions around that.  Perhaps you could post your whole query as to get a real picture of whats going on.

Comment: @paqogomez I'll edit the OP

Comment: Well, that is the whole query.. whew.  So what happens when you remove `and fd.fs_dt between '1/1/14' and 'now' `?

Comment: Also realize that when you do `date_part('month', fd.fs_dt) = 1` you're going to get BOTH january 2013 and january 2014.

Comment: Another thing.  You are grouping by `fd.fs_dt` this will give you one record for each date, i'm not sure, but i dont think thats what you want.  Perhaps you need to post another question with the second part of that query.  I think that is a different query that requires a pivot.

Comment: Bottom line, you have a LOT of things going into and wrong with this query.  I'd suggest breaking the ideas into smaller queries and fixing the problems, then putting them back together will be more straight forward.

Comment: Get rid of your second inner join `
inner join (select sum(fd.amount)
    from financial_data fd
    where fd.fs_dt between '1/1/13' and '1/1/14'
    ) Last_yr
    on fa.acct_no = fd.acct_no
`

Comment: @paqogomez Thank you for the advice on getting rid of the group by. I've been trying to figure that part out for a while.

Comment: When I remove the fd.fs_dt between '1/1/14' and current_date, it puts data into may-december, which is what I don't want that, because that would be 2013's data, when I need 2014's data

Comment: Any idea of how to fix the date_part? @paqogomez

Comment: And is there any way for me to give you a huge upvote on your reputation?

Comment: Fixing the date part might be as easy as including and datepart year = 2013 after the datepart month = 1.  As far as the rep upvote is concerned.. lol. just accept my answer and we'll be good. ;)

Comment: Oh, and never mind about those other questions I asked you @paqogomez I figured them out. On the date_part, I put and('year', fd.fs_dt) = 2014. That fixed the part about removing the fd.fs_dt between.

Comment: realize that you are trying to do calculations for 2 years in a single query.  So somethings got to give.  Either break this into two queries, one for each year. (preferred) or look at both years simultaneously and `case` each year specifically in the columns.

Comment: alright. I have a design pre-made for me, I'm just doing the programming. I'll see if eclipse would let me separate the years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split these out into two columns.  Each looking at the date range and returning the amount value or zero

```
select
  sum(case when datecolumn between '1/1/13' and '1/1/14' then amount else 0 end) as last_yr_tot,
  sum(case when datecolumn between '1/1/14' and current_date then amount else 0 end) as ytd
from
  myTable
```

[Check this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1d5a5/1)

Note that `datecolumn` and `myTable` must be replaced by your own date column and table names.  As `date` is a reserved word in postgresql, it doesnt look much like a column name.