# Using Least with DatePart?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm running a query during the month of august, but I want to convert it to a `date_part` function.

Here's the original query.

```
SELECT avg(CASE WHEN date = LEAST(current_date-1,'8/31/14') THEN bo ELSE NULL END) end_bo 
From <table>
```

What I'm trying to do, is plug `LEAST` into the one below.

```
SELECT avg(CASE WHEN date_part('month', date) = 8 and date_part('year', date) = 2014 THEN bo ELSE NULL END) end_bo
From <table>
```

The problem is, I don't see where I can plug it in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one looks to see which of those dates are earlier, `currentdate` or `Aug 31 2014`, if it is equal to `date` it returns `bo`.

While the second one tests to see if the current month is `aug 2014` and returns `bo`.

To apply the same logic to the second query, it might look like this:

```
SELECT avg(CASE 
           WHEN least(date_part('month', currentdate), 8) = date_part('month', date) 
                  and date_part('year', date) = 2014 
           THEN bo 
           ELSE NULL 
           END) end_bo
```

This would look at the current month, find if it was lower than 8, compare it with `date` month, if equal return `bo`.

[`LEAST`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-conditional.html) simply returns the lowest number in a list.  So `least(9,8)` (sept, aug) would return 8.

Comment: Oh, and hello Pada. :)

Comment: Hello paqo. We meet again. And you answered another of my questions. I give you my thanks.

Comment: @Padagomez You are very welcome.  Am I mistaken or is this a continuation of the same query [we worked on in may](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23571223/case-in-select-after-sum#comment36178450_23571223)?

Comment: It isn't the same query, but it has the same layout. Having a row for each month and such.